# How to export a TypeScript module for SystemJS?

Tags: typescript, module, ecmascript-6, systemjs, tsc

On my website I want to import a `FancyModule` using [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs), so that I can create instances of classes which this module exports.

So what I want to achieve is this (within a ECMAScript 2015-compatible website):

```
SystemJS.import('MyFancyModule').then(function(MyFancyModule) {
  var myFancyInstance = new MyFancyModule.MyFancyClass('Test');
  console.log(myFancyInstance.text);
});
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: MyFancyModule.MyFancyClass is not a constructor(…)

Here is my TypeScript module:

```
export module MyFancyModule {
  export class MyFancyClass {
    public text: string;

    constructor(text: string) {
      this.text = text;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my TypeScript compiler setting (**tsconfig.json**):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outFile": "dist/browser/MyFancyModule.js",
    "rootDir": "src/ts",
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

Which compiles my TypeScript module into:

```
System.register("MyFancyModule", [], function(exports_1, context_1) {
  "use strict";
  var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
  var MyFancyModule;
  return {
    setters: [],
    execute: function() {
      (function(MyFancyModule) {
        var MyFancyClass = (function() {
          function MyFancyClass(text) {
            this.text = text;
          }

          return MyFancyClass;
        }());
        MyFancyModule.MyFancyClass = MyFancyClass;
      })(MyFancyModule = MyFancyModule || (MyFancyModule = {}));
      exports_1("MyFancyModule", MyFancyModule);
    }
  }
});
```

For me it looks like `MyFancyModule` is properly exported but I don't know why I cannot access the `MyFancyClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I managed to reproduce your example.

It looks like with this setup, the file - `MyFancyModule.ts` - is already a module in itself. When you do

```
export module MyFancyModule {
```

you create a nested module within it.

This code should work with everything else unchanged:

```
    SystemJS.import('MyFancyModule').then(function(MyFancyModule) {
        var myFancyInstance = new MyFancyModule.MyFancyModule.MyFancyClass('Test');
        console.log(myFancyInstance.text);
    });
```

Alternatively, you can remove `export module` from the .ts file and have `export class` at the top level - then your original import will work.

Comment: — Can you please have a look at https://github.com/bennyn/systemjs-example ? I pushed the project there end removed the `export module MyFancyModule` from the TypeScript code but it still doesn't work. :'(

Comment: I don't know the reason, but it does work only if module name in SystemJS.import matches exactly the name in SystemJS.register, so you need to do this:       `SystemJS.config({map: {MyFancyModule: 'js/MyFancyModule.js'}});

      SystemJS.import('MyFancyModule')`. I created a PR

Answer (score 1):

Typescript takes care of how to load the modules from the different module systems that it supports.
The idea is that you have a specific syntax of doing that (in typescript) and based on the module you specify to the compiler (for example in the `tsconfig.json`) it will generate the appropriate code for loading the modules according to the selected module system.

So all you need to do is:

```
import * as MyFancyModule from "MyFancyModule";

var myFancyInstance = new MyFancyModule.MyFancyClass('Test');
console.log(myFancyInstance.text);
```

---

#### Edit

The compiler should generate something like:

```
System.register(["MyFancyModule"], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var MyFancyModule;
    var myFancyInstance;
    return {
        setters:[
            function (MyFancyModule_1) {
                MyFancyModule = MyFancyModule_1;
            }],
        execute: function() {
            myFancyInstance = new MyFancyModule.MyFancyClass('Test');
            console.log(myFancyInstance.text);
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see there are no traces of this `import from` syntax in the compiled js.

Comment: But `import * as MyFancyModule from "MyFancyModule";` isn't defined in the ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification, is it? Because I want to execute `SystemJS.import` within a ES5 website.

Comment: The `ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification` doesn't support types either but typescript does. Same thing with how you import things in typescript. It compiles your source to a valid js based on the target and module system of your choice. You can read more about how to import modules in the official docs: [Modules > Import](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import)

Comment: I updated my answer with the compiled js which shows that the `import from` part is just ts.

Comment: Thanks Nitzan, but it's still now what I am looking for. I don't want that the registered module already creates the instance and does the `console.log`. I just want that the module exposes it's classes to the application which imports the module.