# React/Typescript Ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, typescript, systemjs, ag-grid

i'm trying to use ag-grid in my application with react and typescript.
ag-grid .d.ts files are inside the project so i can't install then with typings install --save...

The problem is when i try to import it...

```
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
```

I'm using VSCode... it shows me "[ts] cannot find module", while compiling same thing.

More info about the application:
**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmitOnError": false,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "jsx": "react"
    }
}
```

**typings.json**

```
{
  "name": "focco-sys-jspm",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "registry:npm/react#15.0.1+20160601175240",
    "react-addons-update": "registry:npm/react-addons-update#0.14.0+20160324044346",
    "react-dom": "registry:npm/react-dom#15.0.1+20160705210405",
    "react-router": "registry:npm/react-router#2.4.0+20160811060709"
  }
}
```

Finally i tried to include the references in my typings file
**index.d.ts**

```
/// <reference path="modules/react-addons-update/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="modules/react-dom/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="modules/react-router/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="modules/react/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../jspm_packages/npm/ag-grid@5.4.0/main.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../jspm_packages/npm/ag-grid-react@5.4.0/main.d.ts" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export a TypeScript module for SystemJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120576/how-to-export-a-typescript-module-for-systemjs)

Comment: I'm using ag-grid and ag-grid-react with no custom config, no typings.  Is this due to an older version of TS that is now fixed in 2.4 upwards?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `typings.json` to

```
{
  "name": "focco-sys-jspm",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "registry:npm/react#15.0.1+20160601175240",
    "react-addons-update": "registry:npm/react-addons-update#0.14.0+20160324044346",
    "react-dom": "registry:npm/react-dom#15.0.1+20160705210405",
    "react-router": "registry:npm/react-router#2.4.0+20160811060709",
    "ag-grid": "13.1.x",
    "ag-grid-react": "13.1.x"
  }
}
```

Once you have included these two dependencies go to your root package folder and open a command prompt from there. In the command prompt enter  `npm install`. It should install the `ag-grid` dependencies.